# Composite $n$ such that $\sigma(n) \equiv n+1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, divisor-sum

I'm looking for composite $n$ such that
$$\sigma(n)\equiv n+1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$$

Are there only finitely many? Can this be proved?

This is Sloane's [A070037](https://oeis.org/A070037) but there's not much information in the entry.

Comment: Are we saying that $\sigma(n)$ is the actual sigma function and $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Yes.